# Data exchange finished in CPropertyPage::OnOK?

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog

My dialog box derives from `CPropertyPage`.

I've overridden `OnOK()` in order to run some custom checks. However, it seems that *Dynamic Data Exchange* (DDX) has already completed and my class variables have already been updated when my handler gets called.

I thought DDX happens when I call `CPropertyPage::OnOK()`, which I'm doing at the end of my handler.

In addition, if my code decides the dialog box should not close and returns without calling `CPropertyPage::OkOK()`, the dialog still closes!

How can I run my custom checks before DDX has updated my class variables?

*P.S. It doesn't appear that the MFC source code is installed by default any longer, and none of the install options mention the MFC source code. After Googling, I found a couple of options mentioned. I checked them and I still don't have the MFC source code.*

Comment: These sorts of checks are (IIRC) run by an overridden [`DoDataExchange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class?view=vs-2019#dodataexchange).  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: This check is more complicated. I'm comparing the selected value to another and then I'm seeing if the value exists within a list of values. Would be much simpler if I could just write code in `OnOK()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CPropertyPage::OnOK()` doesn't do the same thing as `CDialogEx::OnOK()`.

Property pages should override `CPropertyPage::OnKillActive()` instead. This method allows me to perform custom validation and return `FALSE` without calling `CPropertyPage::OnKillActive()` to prevent the dialog box from closing, or switching to another tab.